# How to use Cookies in Javascript to record the count of the users visit?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a webpage that shows one of the two images randomly. I want to determine whether the user saw either of the images. And if the user visits the page next time, I want to show them the same image they saw previously. I want to use cookies to record how many times a user has seen each image.

```
<section class="stage">
      <figure class="artImage" id="artImageId"><span class="shadow"></span></figure>
    <p>Test</p>
    <script>
        var color = "blue";
         if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
             color = "green";
         }
        document.getElementById("artImageId").style.background = color;
    </script>
```

And I'm sure I need to use something like the following but I find it very difficult. Some sample or tips will be a great help! I would love to hear from you!

```
var $cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since cookies can be manipulated like simple strings I would recommend you do something as follows;
First, when a user visit the website and sees a certain image, let's say it's "green", you save the following into the cookie:

```
document.cookie = "image=green;visited=1;
```

And you always check for the cookie before setting it again by doing the following:

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
If(cookie!= null && cookie!=undefined){
If(cookie.length>0){
var imageSeen = cookie.split(";")[0].split("=")[1];
var seenCount= parseInt(cookie.split(";")[1].split("=")[1]);

//Not first time visit!!
seenCount++;

ImageToShow= imageSeen;//just do wtv u need to to show the imageSeen

//Then save the cookie again

document.cookie = "image=green;visited="+seenCount+";";


}}else{
//Treat as first time visit
document.cookie = "image=green;visited=1;";
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

**Don't reinvent the wheel**, use a small cross-browser library like [cookie.js](https://github.com/florian/cookie.js) to read/write/remove cookies.

If you don't have to share the information with a server (Cookies are sent to the server automatically when you make a request to the server on the same domain), another option is to store the information locally by using the browser `localStorage` API.

Here is a complete [JSFiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/kuwjo18r/) so you can understand how it works and see it's easier to use than manipulating document cookies without using a third-party library.

Every time you **Run** it or you click the **Bootstrap** button, a random image is loaded (it can be the same one) and the number of times the image is seen is incremented.

Use F12 to view browser console and display the information.

You can view localStorage keys and values in **Application/Local Storage** tab of Developers Tools (F12 in Chrome and Firefox).